# How to extract data from word to excel when we have different number of lines in different text files

Tags: python, excel, parsing, split, extract

I have many text files to extract data from to excel. Some files have one line into data like: `data: binary\n AAA`. I need the "AAA" part so I use:

```
itemData = item.split("data:")[0].strip() 
itemlast = item.split()[-1].strip()
```

However, other text files have two or three lines. My question is:
How can I make a loop to start when it finds the word (data), parse everything that comes into it, and stops before the next data line?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work:

```
txt = '''
data: binary
 AAA
data: binary
 AAA
 BBB
 CCC
data: binary
 AAA
 ZZZQQ
data: binary
 XXX1
 xxx2
'''

lst = txt.split('\ndata:')[1:]  # use [1:] if first record empty
for s in lst:
   print(s.replace('\n','').replace('binary','').strip())
```

Output

```
AAA
AAA BBB CCC
AAA ZZZQQ
XXX1 xxx2
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried it and the output is a sequence of [ ] [ ]. Does it make a difference that I use PyCharm? I have the second "replace" in orange which indicates there's something wrong.

Comment: I ran the code above directly in a Python terminal (Win10 \ Python 3.7). I get the same results.How are you running it when you get the [ ][ ]?  Try running it directly in a terminal and check the results.This should help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemlast = "".join(item.split("data:")[1].replace(" ","").strip().split("\n")[1:])
```

I put this inside a loop and it works perfectly now! Thank you!